# Firebase Realtime database count active users by status value

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a service that detects the presence when the user is online, away and offline in firebase.

**presence.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "@angular/fire/database";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { tap, map, switchMap, first } from "rxjs/operators";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { SuperUserService } from "./../services/superuser.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class PresenceService {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private superuser: SuperUserService
  ) {
    console.log("Verificação de status em execução");
    this.setName();
    this.updateOnUser().subscribe();
    this.updateOnDisconnect().subscribe();
    this.updateOnAway();
  }

  getPresence(uid: string) {
    return this.db.object(`status/${uid}`).valueChanges();
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  }

  async setPresence(status: string) {
    const user = await this.getUser();
    if (user) {
      return this.db.object(`status/${user.uid}`).update({
        status,
        timestamp: this.timestamp,
      });
    }
  }

  async setName() {
    const user = await this.getUser();
    if (user) {
      return this.db.object(`status/${user.uid}`).update({
        nome: this.superuser.user.displayName,
      });
    }
  }

  get timestamp() {
    return firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  }

  updateOnUser() {
    const connection = this.db
      .object(".info/connected")
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(map((connected) => (connected ? "online" : "offline")));

    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap((user) => (user ? connection : of("offline"))),
      tap((status) => this.setPresence(status))
    );
  }

  updateOnDisconnect() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return this.db
            .object(`status/${user.uid}`)
            .query.ref.onDisconnect()
            .update({
              status: "offline",
              timestamp: this.timestamp,
            });
        }
      })
    );
  }

  async signOut() {
    await this.setPresence("offline");
    await this.afAuth.signOut();
  }

  
  updateOnAway() {
    document.onvisibilitychange = (e) => {
      if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
        this.setPresence("away");
      } else {
        this.setPresence("online");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Firebase path**

[image: firebase]

With this in mind I am wanting to implement a way to bring up how many users are active (**online and away**) *Ex:  15 active users*

I tried this, but it only brings me if exist or not

```
ref.child("status").orderByChild("status").equalTo("online")
.once("value",snapshot => {
if (snapshot.exists()){
  // if exist
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the number of online users with your current data structure, you can keep the same query as you have but then [use `snapshot.numChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#numchildren) to determine the number of online users it returned.

---

If you want to show counts of both online and offline users with your current data structure, you can either:

- Use a second query for the offline users, and use the same approach as above to get the count.
- Use a single read without a condition on the `status` field, and then count the individual nodes in your application code with:

```
ref.child("status")
.once("value",snapshot => {
  let onlineCount=0, offlineCount=0;
  snapshot.forEach((user) => {
    const status = user.child("status").val();
    if (status === "online) onlineCount++
    else if (status === "offline) offlineCount++
    else console.error(`Unexpected status '${status}' for user ${user.key}`);
  })
  console.log(`Online: ${onlineCount}, Offline: ${offlineCount}`);
});
```

---

If you're reading all these user profiles to simply show two counters in your app, you're wasting quite a bit of bandwidth (and thus money) for both yourself and your users. Consider storing the actual counts that you want to display in the database itself, and updating them as each user goes online/offline in something like Cloud Functions.